# Set, then get, or first get, then set?

Tags: terminology, logic

In some abstract programming languages there is a concept "setter and getter".

Generalizing, should this be the opposite, i.e. "Getter and setter"?
I would theorize that one should first get something --- only then set it.

Comment: Together, those have been name *accessor*s. How would the thing to be gotten have a defined value? (*Not saying* it's not possible, or even conventional depending on environment. *writers&readers* rubs the wrong way, doesn't it?)

Comment: In programming contexts, I've seen “getters and setters” more often than “setters and getters”. What's the difference anyway? The two expressions mean the same thing and I don't see a didactic difference.

Comment: You need both. Which one you mention first is of no consequence. However, read-only properties that only have a getter are not uncommon.

Comment: @gnasher729 why do you say that it is of no consequence? To set something you first need to get it, wouldn't you agree? So okay, the interpreter "knows" what to get and will get it even if the function to so **appears** after the function to set it --- but it's still just interpreter aesthetics.